# Extend GPIO ports or another options for use an HAT en 2" LCD SCREEN

Tags: gpio

I have a project to make a small robot based on Raspberry Pi 4. I am using an Adeept Motor V2 HAT that uses all the GPIO ports to control all the elements of the robot. I would like to add a 2" LCD screen connected via the SPI interface. Unfortunately, it is already used by the Adeept HAT. I would like to find an extension card that allows me to increase the number of GPIO ports or find another way to connect this screen via the SPI interface in addition to the Adeept HAT.
what are the options ?